# Getting 'Type Mismatch' Error but program still works

Tags: ms-access, vba, runtime-error, type-mismatch

I am trying to set the values of a multi-select list box in **MS Access** using **VBA**. The indexes for the values I want to select are saved in a table called **Index**. I want to retrieve them from the table, split them (because they are delimited with a semi-colon), and then set the list box values. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub SetListBox()
    Dim Indexes As String
    Dim IndexArray() As String

    Indexes = rsIndex!EIndex  //Gets the semi-colon delimited value from 'Index' table
    IndexArray = Split(Indexes, ";")  //Array of strings holding the different indexes

    ReDim IndexArrayLong(UBound(IArray)) As Long  //Creating an array of Long with the same length as IndexArray

    For i = 0 To UBound(IndexArray)
        IndexArrayLong(i) = CLng(IndexArray(i)) //Converts the Strings into Longs and places them in Long Array
        Me.listBox.Selected(IArrayL(i)) = True //Sets listbox values
    Next

End Sub
```

Upon some research I found that the indexes of List Box values are of Long data type, which is why I convert the Strings to Longs. The sub is successfully setting the list box values but,  before it does, it gives me

> Run Time-Error: '13'  Type Mismatch

and it highlights this line of code:

```
IndexArrayLong(i) = CLng(IndexArray(i))
```

I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting the error or the solution for it. Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One or more of your strings is not purely an integer.  Have you tried looping through and printing them?  Does your original string end with the delimiter?  That may give you an empty string as the last value of the array, which can't be converted to a number.

Comment: It was the semi-colon at the end! Thank you so much! I can't believe I missed that!